# How to disable a dynamically created <li> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created `<ul>` containing three `<li>`.i want to make disable one of my `<li>` on certain condition and insert some text in other `<li>` but failed.!

**`code`**

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.className = "dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination";
    var UL = document.createElement('ul');
    var L1 = document.createElement('li');
    L1.className = 'prev';
    var A1 = document.createElement('a');
    A1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('← Previous'));
    A1.id = 'B1';
    L1.appendChild(A1);
    UL.appendChild(L1);
    var L3 = document.createElement('li');
    L3.className = 'active';
    var A3 = document.createElement('a');
    A3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('1'));
    L3.appendChild(A3);
    UL.appendChild(L3);
    d.appendChild(UL);
    var L2 = document.createElement('li');
    L2.className = 'next';
    var A2 = document.createElement('a');
    A2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Next →'));
    L2.appendChild(A2);
    A2.id = 'B2';
    UL.appendChild(L2);
   var root = document.getElementById('rose');
   root.appendChild(d);
```

i want to B1 disable. i have tried following code:

**`script`**

```
  $('#B1').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: as you are using jQuery, you would have done it very easily using jQuery rather than JavaScript.

Comment: There is no "disabled" attribute for `li` elements. What do you want a "disabled `li`" to do? Is it supposed to disable its child input controls?

Comment: <li> don't have disabled state: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp

Comment: actually i have click function on it, I do not want to call it, thats y making it disable...

Comment: $(this).off(); not working @Jai

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi you have to specify the event in the method `$(this).off('click')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no disabled state for a li element, you can simulate the desired behavior like this:

```
$('#B1').css("color","gray").css("text-decoration","none");
```

Which will make it appear as if disabled (it will not be underlined and will appear grayed-out).

If in addition you need to disable the event listeners attached to it, you will have to use [off()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp):

```
$('#B1').off("click");
```

Furthermore, if the element is a link, you will have to prevent it from being clickable, in the following way:

```
$('#B1').click(function() {
    $(this).preventDefault();  // prevent the default action
    $(this).stopPropagation(); // prevent event from bubbling up
    return false;              // just to be sure
}
```

Comment: Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault(). Check the documentation for [jQuery.on, section "The event handler and its environment"](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That's why I added "just to be sure", as we do not know what environment OP's code runs on (jQuery/browser version etc). Doesn't hurt.

Comment: Doesn't help either (unless the OP is running a modified version of jQuery)

Answer (score 3):

try with `.off()`:

```
$('#B1').off("click");
```

FYI:

Only form input elems are having property to get disabled, whether that is type `text`, `select checkbox buttons` etc.